# Multi filtro no web.xml com struts2

Tags: struts2

O web.xml que configurei tem dois filtros que funcionam muito bem em requisições http  do browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Meu XML</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Mas quando faço requisições jQuery `$.get('url')` somente o primeiro filtro funciona.

Se observar o web.xml, estou usando o struts-convention para actions anotadas. o primeiro filtro é para capturar a action na requisição e assimilar com a action que está anotada, o segundo filtro é para o controle da session do hibernate para evitar o `LazyInitializationException`

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Resolvi trocando a ordem dos `filter-mapping` agradeço a ajuda.

Para quem tiver problema com `lazyInitializationExeception` está é a solução!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi trocando a ordem dos filter-mapping agradeço a ajuda. Para quem tiver problema com lazyInitializationExeception está é a solução!